# What is the original reference to Ness' entrance in Super Smash Bros.?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl, super-smash-bros-melee, earthbound, super-smash-bros

When starting a game, Ness enters the battle in an explosion where he appears a little charred. I have not played Earthbound a lot, but I have read and watched quite a lot about that game.

What is the Earthbound reference to Ness exploding?

Comment: This is somewhat of a lore question, and that makes it on topic.

Comment: @Ender No, this is asking why Ness's entrance is the way it is, which only a dev can answer, which makes it off-topic.

Comment: it looks to me like it's asking which reference the explosion is making, which is a lore question.

Comment: As Pikachu comes out from a PokeBall, Luigi jumps from a pipe and Yoshi's egg hatches, Ness explodes when a match starts. So that is my doubt. Which Earthbound thing references that explode?

Comment: @ender and frank I think we can all agree, it's lore *and* a developer question and therefore very off topic.

Comment: @DavidM Lore questions are *on-topic* as per community consensus at the meta post, [Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7696/4797) Voting to reopen as per that meta post.

Comment: From http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "What topics can I ask here? ... Plot and characters in games..." Is that off-topic?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you know, Ness made his debut in the game EarthBound for the SNES. Now one of the PSI abilities that he, as well as another player named Poo, can learn is called PSI Teleport. As the name suggests, this PSI power gives you the ability to warp to places you've already visited. There are two versions of this power-up, PSI Teleport α (you warp by running in a straight line), and PSI Teleport β (you warp by running in a circle). Now the problem with PSI Teleport is that if you happen to run into something while performing the move, you won't teleport. When you hit something, Ness and his friends appear to be burnt. THIS is what you see when Ness makes his entrance onto the stage in Smash Bros. Brawl: it's the same effect that occurs if you run into something while attempting PSI Teleport.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: Is it like this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-nySRs9yT8

Answer (score 3):

Ness's intro animation is a reference to his PSI Teleport ability from Earthbound:

> How Teleport works is that the user begins to run at an ever-accelerating speed, and when the maximum speed is reached, the characters run off the map and spawn at the desired location. Colliding with something before reaching the maximum speed abruptly ends the teleportation process, causing the party to briefly be covered in black soot.
>
> https://earthbound.fandom.com/wiki/Teleport

[image: Teleport Fail]